# Make Animations

Tags: java, animation, swt, widget

I have to make some animated design with lots of pretty effects and color gradients in a SWT compliant way ...

I assume what I try to mean is not clear as water so I'll try to explain more...
I have an RCP application in which I need to have a special page whose content is fed by a class that sends it either beans or strings (or postcards or whatever, it can have to get almost anything) and has to make a nice presentation of all that it gets by building artistical representation of it and animating the whole.

The artistic transformation here is not the problem (I'll handle it and let all freedom to my artistic sick mind) but the problem is to find any framework or plugin that is able to build pretty animations and all the stuff in a SWT shell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Timing Framework](https://timingframework.dev.java.net/) or [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident). Both of them based on the notion of changing bean property values, which would work for SWT or Swing.

You'd have to read about them to see which one you like more. For simple effects Trident looks easier, but it should be your personal choice.

Comment: Thank for tha answer but in the end I am not going to use an swt based solution but I'll prefer an SWT-AWT bridge to have features such as Java2D and such...
But thanks ^^

Comment: Even better. The libraries I suggested were built to be used with Java2D in a first place. SWT-AWT bridge will simply allow you to use Java2D but will NOT help you to do the animation. Java2D has not built-in animation features. so you kinda kgot no choice now :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this could help or not
http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/stw/stw.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it was a quite old post. My problem was during an internship that led nowhere (office boss did not clearly know what he wanted). So this problem got dropped. Thanks though !